# CI base_url() confusion

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

say i have this code,

```
<a href="register">Join</a>
```

that link would be on the homepage, the url of that homepage would be,

> localhost/Project/main

main is the controller and there is an index function that loads the view for the homepage. I set up the header navigation and footer as templates so in my index function i'd have.

```
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('templates/navigation');
        $this->load->view('homepage');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

When i click on the join link which is located in the navigation template, the url will be,

> localhost/Project/main/register

on the register function on main controller i put a simple echo function to see if it works and it is working.

the problem is that im confused, i searched on how to properly link from views to another views in CI and i am seeing the base_url() or site_url() function used, i use base_url because i took out the index.php on my link with .htaccess

the confusion is that if i use the base_url() function say,

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>main/register">Join</a>
```

and ofcourse the base_url on my config is localhost/Project/, so i expect the link to also go to the main/controller and be like,

localhost/Project/main/register but what i get is,

> http://localhost/Project/localhost/Project/main/register

What im confused is that i am thought or still am thinking that if i ever click on the link by url would refresh or something. or am i wrong?

i know my confusion may seem simple to others but atm im too muddleheaded that i don't have any idea where i am supposed to go to clarify this. although i could just use the first  i just want to understand why..

Comment: What rules you have defined in your .htaccess file?

Comment: Please check .htaccess file and also make sure url helper is being included in autoload.php

Comment: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: and yes, url is in autoload.php, $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

so far i have only listed url..

Comment: Base URL should be absolute, including the protocol, please check $config['base_url'] value in config file.

Comment: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/Project/';

Comment: @JMCanson you should include the whole address, including protocol: `http://localhost/Project/`

Answer (score 1):

## No `index.php`

*You've probably done this already, but just to be complete...*

If you want to have your addresses without the `index.php` in them, you need to do two things:

First, remove the `index.php` from your `config.php`.

On line 32, change:

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Second, add rewrite to your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

## `base_url()` or `site_url()`

CodeIgniter tries to guess the `base_url` of your website, if it's wrong, you can change it in your `config.php` file on line 20, just above the `index_page`. It is encouraged that you set this manually.

`base_url()` prints, as its name suggests, the base URL that is either set in your `config.php` file, or guessed by CodeIgniter. Use this for example to provide absolute paths to `css` or `js` files, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=base_url()?>assets/style.css">
```

`site_url()` generates the whole URL for your `controller/method`. Use it like this:

```
<a href="<?=site_url('main/register')?>">Register</a>
```

If your `base_url` is for example `http://localhost/Project/`, this will generate `http://localhost/Project/main/register`.

Comment: I followed guides online on how to remove the index.php and indeed i have removed it.. my url is working fine without the index.php

although on my config, i still had the index.php as my config['index_page']

what does it do?

Comment: Well, CodeIgniter considers `$config['base_url']."/".$config['index_page']` to be the "homepage". By default, going to `http://localhost/Projects` would indeed redirect you to the `index.php` file (or at least it used to). I remember the 2.x documentation mentioning that this should be removed from the configuration file. Haven't noticed it in the 3.x docs however, maybe no longer necessary.